# alternative to "!is.null()" in R

Tags: r

my R code ends up containing plethora of statements of the form:

```
if (!is.null(aVariable)) { 
     do whatever 
}
```

But this kind of statement is hard to read because it contains two negations. I would prefer something like:

```
 if (is.defined(aVariable)) { 
      do whatever 
 }
```

Does a `is.defined` type function that does the opposite of !is.null exist standard in R?

cheers,
yannick

Comment: Where does aVariable come from?  is it an element in a vector, a global or non-vector argument to a function?  I may have more suggestions.

Comment: perhaps 'exists' is close to what you are looking for

Comment: see Harlan's comment below about 'exists'...

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You may be better off working out what value type your function or code accepts, and asking for that:

```
if (is.integer(aVariable))
{
  do whatever
}
```

This may be an improvement over isnull, because it provides type checking.  On the other hand, it may reduce the genericity of your code.

Alternatively, just make the function you want:

```
is.defined = function(x)!is.null(x)
```

Comment: The name `is.defined` isn't quite right since you can declare a variable with the value `NULL`.  Try, e.g. `x <- NULL; x`.  `isnt.null` would be a more appropriate name for the function.

Answer (score 24):

If it's just a matter of easy reading, you could always define your own function :

```
is.not.null <- function(x) !is.null(x)
```

So you can use it all along your program.

```
is.not.null(3)
is.not.null(NULL)
```

Answer (score 10):

Ian put this in the comment, but I think it's a good answer:

```
if (exists("aVariable"))
{
  do whatever
}
```

note that the variable name is quoted.

Comment: I don't think this is the same. `exists` tests whether the variable is bound. `is.null` assumes the variable is bound, and tests whether or not its content is the object NULL. They're not interchangeable.

Answer (score 8):

I have also seen:

```
if(length(obj)) {
  # do this if object has length
  # NULL has no length
}
```

I don't think it's great though. Because some vectors can be of length 0. `character(0)`, `logical(0)`, `integer(0)` and that might be treated as a NULL instead of an error.

Answer (score 3):

To handle undefined variables as well as nulls, you can use `substitute` with `deparse`:

```
nullSafe <- function(x) {
  if (!exists(deparse(substitute(x))) || is.null(x)) {
    return(NA)
  } else {
    return(x)
  }
}

nullSafe(my.nonexistent.var)
```

Answer (score 2):

The `shiny` package provides the convenient functions `validate()` and `need()` for checking that variables are both available and valid. `need()` evaluates an expression. If the expression is not valid, then an error message is returned. If the expression is valid, `NULL` is returned. One can use this to check if a variable is valid. See `?need` for more information.

I suggest defining a function like this:

```
is.valid <- function(x) {
  require(shiny)
  is.null(need(x, message = FALSE))  
}
```

This function `is.valid()` will return `FALSE` if `x` is `FALSE`, `NULL`, `NA`, `NaN`, an empty string `""`, an empty atomic vector, a vector containing only missing values, a logical vector containing only `FALSE`, or an object of class `try-error`. In all other cases, it returns `TRUE`.

That means, `need()` (and `is.valid()`) covers a really broad range of failure cases. Instead of writing:

```
if (!is.null(x) && !is.na(x) && !is.nan(x)) {
  ...
}
```

one can write simply:

```
if (is.valid(x)) {
  ...
}
```

With the check for class `try-error`, it can even be used in conjunction with a `try()` block to silently catch errors: (see https://csgillespie.github.io/efficientR/programming.html#communicating-with-the-user)

```
bad = try(1 + "1", silent = TRUE)
if (is.valid(bad)) {
  ...
}
```